# Remotely activating a javascript function through a php request

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am somewhat new to html/php/web-design, and i created an html page that can create a message via hovering over buttons.

```html
<button class="letter" onmouseover="Over(65)">A</button><br>
```

and the javascript function, Over()

```js
function Over(X){
    console.log("Over " + String.fromCharCode(X));
    let x = '<div class="out"><p id="text">';
    x += document.getElementById("text").innerHTML;
    x += String.fromCharCode(X);
    x += "</p></div>";
    $("div.out").replaceWith(x);
}
```

*put simply, hover over button -> call Over() -> add letter to text*

however, while exploring PHP, i got the idea to combine it with another project i had done earlier, using a function that can send chrome OS notifications. (functions at bottom)

My goal for this is to have a column of buttons on the right for letters, 2 buttons on the left for **Back** and **Send**.  The **Back** Already works just using
`.slice(0, document.getElementById("text").innerHTML.length-1)`  Now i need to figure out how to make the send function output a notification to all other Windows/tabs *i dont know if thats the right word*

[reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdFnO.png)

[Page layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThAFJ.png)

*If this is not enough info or if anyone needs a clearer explanation, i will take feedback* <3

```js
function notifyMe(
 body = "Notification Body",
 title = 'Notification title'
) {
 if (Notification.permission !== 'granted')
  Notification.requestPermission();
 else {
  var notification = new Notification('Notification title',{
   icon: 'icon.png',
   body: "Notification Body",
  });
  notification.onclick = function() {
   window.open('https://stackoverflow.com/');
  };
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be using PHP and JavaScript. To make it easier, it is just one or the other. But, you can create a php  tag in HTML by saying `<script type=text/php>` I am pretty sure, and have them communicate on the same page.

You could just use `element.onmouseover = function() { // YOUR CODE HERE }` and then send out a remote that gets picked up on php.
I don't use php, so sorry if I can't answer how to pick the remote up on php.